# Can pulmonary infarction be asymptomatic?

Tags: pathology, pathogenesis, lungs

I think it can because there are many parts in lungs.
Like for some COPD patients.
However, I am not sure if COPD patients can have infarction.

Lungs have parallel circulation.
Red infarct is possible there.
Blood can flow there.
One symptom should be at least pain.
So now, I think no asymptomatic possible.
But still, I am not sure.

Can pulmonary infarction be asymptomatic?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

No. Based on experience. Lungs are very active organs.